# And Or condition in cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp

What would be the conditions array be in the find query in CakePhp.
The MySql query is:

```
sc.country = '".$country."' and (sc.city='".$city."' or sc.state='".$city."')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this way (even mentioned in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) )

```
$conditions=array(
    "sc.country" => "yourcondition",
    "OR" => array(
        "sc.city" => "cityname",
        "sc.state" => "statename"
    )
));
```

output will be :-

`sc`.`country` = 'yourcondition' AND ((`sc`.`city`='cityname') OR (`sc`.`state` = 'statename'))

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code

```
$this->YourModel->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'sc.country'=>"$country",
        'OR'=>array('sc.city'=>"$city",
            'Or'=>array('sc.state'=>"$city")
            )   
        )   
        )
    );
```

Below is my demo code sqldump

[image]

Comment: sure? Or inside another Or?
isn't there a way to do it using an AND and an OR?